# Streams in dart lag a step behind

Tags: dart, flutter

I read an article by Filip Hracek @filiph that

> One disadvantage that stems from the asynchronicity of streams is that when you build a StreamBuilder, it always shows initialData first (because it is available synchronously) and only then does it show the first event coming from the Stream. This can lead to a flash (one frame) of missing data. There are ways to prevent this — stay tuned for a more detailed article.

I am facing this issue, and I need to know the ways to prevent the flash. It would be great if someone knows the way. I am adding new data to my sink, and then accessing my stream builder snapshot to get the data. However, it returns the initial data which is null or some seed value if I use rxdart. I want the latest data, I tried using `async-` await, but it didn't help. I am setting the `snapshot.data` value in a Map, with index associated with my itemBuilder.

**Here is a sample code**

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, int index){
     return checkboxListTile(
      title: Text(xyz)
      value: valueMap[key[index]];
      onChanged:(value){bloc.myController.sink.add(value); 
                 valueMap[key[index]] = snapshot.data;}
      );
   }
);
```

The `snapshot.data` returns old values. So it basically lags one step. I understand its an `asynchronous` and `synchronous` issue. But I need a way around.

Comment: There is no way to make Stream listening synchronous. I'm not sure what is meant by "There are ways to prevent this ", but I am not aware of any.

Comment: You can have a sync stream - but _subscribing_ to it is still asynchronous .

Comment: So @JonahWilliams, how do you suggest I get that missing data set properly. Data from snapshot lags by a step. So, I have to tap twice every time for the onChanged function to work correctly. May be Filip Hracek( filiph )can answer, but I can't tag him because of low reputation points. Can someone tag him here. Since he wrote that article.

Comment: That sounds more like you are missing a setState, can you add one to your onChanged callback?

Comment: I am not using a stateful widget here. I want to be able to do this using Stateless widgets. I know the functionality would be easier using Stateful widgets, but I am creating custom widgets which will have more functions later on, as the app size increases. And we want to be uniform with the approach.

Comment: That's not a reasonable way to design an app.  stateful widgets are required, that is why they are part of the framework

Comment: I will go with the stateful widgets here. I was thinking of using as BloC as much as possible, to get a better grasp. I am still new to Flutter, and I think we lack coding samples for the use of BloC. Thanks for the help @JonahWilliams

Comment: Just to confirm: @GoPro, what you're seeing is really just a flash (one frame) of old data, correct? Or is it that your StreamBuilder builds with some previous version and then never updates (until user action)? Those are separate issues.

Comment: @flash I used to see one frame of old data. I was able to resolve the issue later on. It was just a synchronization issue on my part.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a hit or miss because I was relying on data being updated by Firestore cloud functions!!!!!!!!!

Depending on how quickly the function executed, the data was not always as expected.